# Error raising while creating a polynomial ring over GF(5^2)

Tags: python, sage

I want to work with a polynomial ring over `GF(p^k)` where `p` is prime.

I tried:

```
p = 3
q = 9
Fq.<alpha> = FiniteField(q)
Pol.<x> = PolynomialRing(Fq)
Pol
```

and this raises an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert non-integral float to integer
```

I am using SageMath 8.3. Any idea about why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't have access to Sage 8.3, but this works with Sage 8.4 and later. Can you post more information? The full trace-back for the error?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce this problem. Running Sage 8.3 on [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com):

```
$ sage-8.3
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 8.3, Release Date: 2018-08-03                     │
│ Create a "Sage Worksheet" file for the notebook interface.         │
│ Enhanced for CoCalc.                                               │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
sage: p = 3
sage: q = 9
sage: Fq.<alpha> = FiniteField(q)
sage: Pol.<x> = PolynomialRing(Fq)
sage: Pol
Univariate Polynomial Ring in x over Finite Field in alpha of size 3^2
```

- Can you reproduce the problem in a fresh Sage session?
- What is your operating system?
- How did you install Sage? (via a package manager? as binaries
  downloaded from the SageMath website? built from source? etc.
- Does this happen in the Sage REPL (in the terminal)?
  In a SageNB worksheet? In the Jupyter Notebook? Other?